# Recursive function too slow for creating hierarchical select list

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a query that gets me a Geo-Structure from the database.

Categories Table (30.000 rows inside):

```
id  title          parent  type 
-------------------------------
1   germany             0     1
2   bavaria             1     2
3   upper bavaria       2     3
4   munich              3     4
6   italy               0     1
7   toscana             6     2
8   city florence       7     3
9   florence            8     4
```

Categories Language Table

```
cid language title
--------------------------
1   en-UK    germany
2   de-DE    deutschland
```

Objects table:

```
id  title   landid  regionid    uregionid   cityid
--------------------------------------------------
1   o1           1         2            3        4
2   o2           1         2            3        4 
3   o3           6         7            8        9
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, l.title AS translated, c.type, c.parent, count(c.id) as cnt
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN objects o ON (o.landid = c.id  OR o.regionid = c.id OR o.uregionid = c.id OR o.cityid = c.id) 
LEFT JOIN category_lang l ON l.cid = c.id AND l.language = "en-UK"
WHERE c.published = 1 AND o.published = 1
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.parent
```

I get an associative array ($tree) with values like here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Germany
            [type] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Italy
            [type] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Bavaria
            [type] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => Toscana
            [type] => 2
            [parent] => 6
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Upper Bavaria
            [type] => 3
            [parent] => 2
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [title] => City Florence
            [type] => 3
            [parent] => 7
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Munich
            [type] => 4
            [parent] => 3
            [cnt] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [title] => Florence
            [type] => 4
            [parent] => 8
            [cnt] => 1
        )

)
```

Then i create a structure that will prepare the display of a select list:

```
public static function buildTree($tree, $root = 0) { 
        $return = array(); 
        foreach($tree as $child) { 
            if($child['parent'] == $root) { 
                $return[] = array( 
                    'name' => $child, 
                    'next' => self::buildTree($tree, $child['id']) 
                ); 
            } 
        } 
        return empty($return) ? null : $return;     
    }
```

Then i send the structure inside $return to a function to create the final select list:

```
public static function buildSelect($tree, $s) {
        $option = '';
        if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
            foreach($tree as $node) {
                $selected = '';
                $class_type = $node['name']['type'];                
                $option .= '<option value="'.$node['name']['id'].'" class="h'.$class_type.'" '.$selected.' data-type="'.$node['name']['type'].'">'
                            .$node['name']['title']. ' (' . $node['name']['cnt'] . ')</option>'
                            . self::buildSelect($node['next'], $s); 
            }
            return $option; 
        }    
    }
```

This all works but if the Geo-Structure gets really big the db query gets terrible slow.
Would appreciate any ideas about how to speed this up, thanks!

Comment: what's the count of your returned data nearly ?

Comment: i get a selectlist that presents the whole structure perfectly, but it gets extremely slow.

Comment: so in selecting data from mysql phase there are no problem even if the data is too big ?

Comment: no, the mysql query is not the problem. works fine with big structures too.

Comment: You might be having memory issues. You could possibly improve things by passing the parameters to the recursive functions by reference ( eg _public static function buildSelect(&$tree, $s) {_ ). This way there is just one copy of them floating around, rather than one copy per level of recursion.

Comment: tried that but no change. still very slow. i don't think its a memory problem, but somewhere in the recursion algorithm there is maybe overload.

Comment: When memory use gets to a critical point the run times will ramp up rapidly as it has to page it in an out, Surprised passing by reference made no difference. When it goes slow does it still finish? If not I would look for a circular reference in your data.

Comment: yes, it finishes, just takes very long. there is plenty of memory so no hard drive actions are happening.

Comment: Second function will be the most memory intensive. First is the one that is having to do a LOT of looping around. If you sort the base data into parent order before calling the functions, then you can modify the loop to terminate early once it finds a parent in the loop that is larger than the one it is searching for.

Comment: I know. Already tried to optimize as much as i can.

Comment: i was asking about the mysql query phase for a reason , if there are not problem with mysql you may be able to skip your first recursion function `buildTree` by using sub-queries to fetch your data from mysql , but first please update your question by the database table structure .

Comment: the table structure is basically like the array output you see above. very simple: `id,title,parent,type`. the cnt is the number of objects in every category.

Comment: You could do the following to reduce the number of iterations required for the same elements. unset($tree[$key]); after your if comparison in the first function.

Comment: you were right. the query is the problem. any idea how to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics seem there, and without setting up a lot of test data it is difficult to do any testing.

The following has a couple of minor tweaks (you will need to change to cope with where you want to keep the compare routine). Possibly not enough to fix the issue. However I would be interested to know what effect it has, and also some timings of which method is taking the time, and how it ramps up:-

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["parent"], $b["parent"]);
}

usort($tree, "cmp");

$recursive_tree = self::buildTree($tree);

echo self::buildSelect($recursive_tree, '');

public static function buildTree(&$tree, $root = 0) 
{ 
    $return = array(); 
    foreach($tree as $child) 
    { 
        if($child['parent'] == $root) 
        { 
            $return[] = array( 
                'name' => $child, 
                'next' => self::buildTree($tree, $child['id']) 
            ); 
        }
        else
        {
            if ($child['parent'] > $root)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    return empty($return) ? null : $return;     
} 


public static function buildSelect(&$tree, $s) 
{
    $option = '';
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) 
    {
        foreach($tree as $node) 
        {
            $selected = '';
            $class_type = $node['name']['type'];                
            $option .= '<option value="'.$node['name']['id'].'" class="h'.$class_type.'" '.$selected.' data-type="'.$node['name']['type'].'">'
                        .$node['name']['title']. ' (' . $node['name']['cnt'] . ')</option>'
                        . self::buildSelect($node['next'], $s); 
        }
        return $option; 
    }    
}
```

Does the output have to be built up, or can be be directly output (even to a temp file)?

EDIT

If your objects table has indexes on landid, regionid, uregionid and cityid (ie, separate indexes on each one) then try this:-

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.type, c.parent, count(c.id) as cnt
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN objects o1 ON o1.landid = c.id AND o1.published = 1
LEFT JOIN objects o2 ON o2.regionid = c.id AND o2.published = 1
LEFT JOIN objects o3 ON o3.uregionid = c.id AND o3.published = 1
LEFT JOIN objects o4 ON o4.cityid = c.id AND o4.published = 1
WHERE c.published = 1 
AND (01.id IS NOT NULL
OR 02.id IS NOT NULL
OR 03.id IS NOT NULL
OR 04.id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY c.id, 
        c.title, 
        c.type, 
        c.parent
ORDER BY c.parent
```

EDIT

Adding in your language table:-

```
SELECT c.id,
        c.title, 
        l.title AS translated, 
        c.type, 
        c.parent, 
        count(c.id) as cnt
FROM category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_lang l ON l.cid = c.id AND l.language = "en-UK"
LEFT OUTER JOIN objects o1 ON o1.landid = c.id AND o1.published = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN objects o2 ON o2.regionid = c.id AND o2.published = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN objects o3 ON o3.uregionid = c.id AND o3.published = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN objects o4 ON o4.cityid = c.id AND o4.published = 1
WHERE c.published = 1 
AND (01.id IS NOT NULL
OR 02.id IS NOT NULL
OR 03.id IS NOT NULL
OR 04.id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY c.id, 
        c.title, 
        translated,
        c.type, 
        c.parent
ORDER BY c.parent
```

As to whether this or the UNION solution is better, that will come down largely to your data. For example this solution will struggle if the 4 id columns in the objects table can have duplicates (unlikely, as I would doubt a city can also be a region).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried the first change with the usort and changed buildTree functtion but its not getting faster so far.

Comment: something is not right. there are only first category parents outputted. the inserted `else` is cutting all the children away.

Comment: There are cases when the sort function puts a deeper child from another country before and it exits then. i changed the cmp function to this, because parent is int: `return ($a < $b) ? -1 : (($a > $b) ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: Is that faster now? My fault for trying to do things quickly and using a string compare. Doh!

Comment: no, like i said it exits too early because of the `else`. There are 30.000 rows and it can happen that another child with a higher ID gets before the correct one.

Comment: @Mike - How can that happen? The array is sorted into the order of the parent id, so the higher id must come after the lower id. If not then something is wrong with the usort (although if the data comes from a database it would be better to sort in the query).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/ykDaKTkj
It comes to parent id 1183. After that id 1305 has as parent with id 1302 and it exits and does not come to id 1063480.

Comment: That is because of the cmp routine you have used. It is sorting based on the array elements, rather than the 'parent' element of each element. Change it to _function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a['parent'] < $b['parent']) ? -1 : (($a['parent'] > $b['parent']) ? 1 : 0);
}_

Comment: yeah i saw that error. i now realized that the db query is too slow with big data. i added the table structure and my query.

Comment: Meeting now, but an OR in a large join clause will almost certainly perform badly.

Comment: You know an alternative?

Comment: Multiple LEFT OUTER JOINs, and then sort out which one you want, or mulitple UNIONed queries.

Comment: Yeah i'm on it...sorting is not working but i will get there. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike - added a suggestion for the SQL.

Comment: Thanks, i extendend my first query a little because i use it for a multilanguage site. my UNION solution works already, but your query look nicer. how to insert the category language table (look above) in it?

Comment: @Mike - Another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Nested Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It is fairly easy to add calculated `tree_left`, `tree_right`, and `tree_depth` to your current `parent`-based model — `parent` stays as primary data, other three will be recalculated on change.

Then, you can use a much simpler select to get items for the whole subtree of categories and thanks to the `tree_depth` column it is easy to calculate correct indentation in your `<select>` element or in listings without any recursion.